# .NET Core - override default build targets

Tags: asp.net-core, msbuild, asp.net-core-2.0, csproj

I have an angular project that I'd like to include in my Visual Studio solution. I added a new project with type ASP.NET Core 2/Empty that has all of the files, excluding the node_modules and similar ones via wildcard directly in csproj.

The problem I'm having is with overriding default build target - when build target is triggered I'd like to call "ng build", but this doesn't happen. Some materials about this can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-targets) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/target-build-order)

1 Attempted to override default build target:

```
 <Target Name="Build">
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Overriding default build" />
 </Target>
```

But still it doesn't execute.

2 Tried to specify DefaultTargets, but it doesn't get called just the same:

```
 <Project DefaultTargets="NgBuild" Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
   ...
 <Target Name="NgBuild">
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Overriding default build" />
 </Target>
```

Only after I add attribute `BeforeTargets="Build"` the message is there.

So the question is - how do I override default build behavior? Ultimately, I'd like to have a target that will invoke `<Exec Command="ng build">` inside of it and doesn't produce an `.exe` and doesn't require any .cs files in the project.

Comment: Why don't you post your entire project file. Order of definitions and how the file is defined does matter in this case.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The reason the `Build` target is not to overridden is because it isn't defined yet at the time your custom target is loaded - your custom target is overridden by the default target.

If you use an SDK-based project file using `<Project Sdk="…">`, the SDK props and targets files (just two msbuild project files) are automatically imported before and after your project file. The `Build` target is actually defined through the import that comes after the project's contents and thus overrides the one you define in the project file.

If you really want to override the `Build` target (more on that later), I suggest you move from implicit SDK imports to explicit SDK imports:

```
<Project>
  <Import Project="Sdk.props" Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web" />
  <!-- Project content -->
  <Import Project="Sdk.targets" Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web" />
  <Target Name="Build">
    <!-- this will override the default Build target. -->
  </Target>
</Project>
```

However, the SDK is built around compiling and generating .NET assemblies. You may find that overriding the `Build` target may lead to unexpected results, including your project not being able to produce output that can be referenced by other projects (if you want that).

If you simply want to add a build step to your project, I suggest adding a custom target that hooks into the exiting build process:

```
<Target Name="NgBuild" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
  <Exec Command="ng build" />
</Target>
```

Comment: My project has zero c# code - it's just pure Angular, and I'd like to have it shown in Visual Studio as such (I don't want dll's when it's built - I want to use angular/cli for build). Your idea was good, but now I get UnsupportedTargetFrameworkError (for both net47 and netstandard20). Any idea how to move on?

Comment: Not use a project?.. I don't think there is a pure typescript / angular project type in VS. Maybe try the "open folder" feature. Personally, I think the typescript support of VSCode is even better than in VS..

Comment: But this is expected, the `Microsoft.NET` Sdks are primarily for building .NET Code. You'd need to make a custom project type importing the minimal MSBuild common props/targets, implement the `CoreCompile` target and also import VS' typescript targets

Answer (score 3):

Seems, you need to specify a new target to solve your problem.

For example in my .csproj I have following lines:

```
  <Target Name="TestTarget">
    <Exec Command="echo hello" />
    <Exec Command="echo goodbye" />
  </Target>
```

To call them, I need to execute the following command:

```
dotnet msbuild /t:TestTarget
```

In this scenario, you can specify commands and order of execution. Hope, this will help.