# Build multiple executables from a single csproj

Tags: .net, msbuild, .net-6.0, roslyn, csproj

I have a large number of .Net6 console apps in a solution which all have mostly the same csproj content and contain a single .cs file which differs from project to project, it gets really anoying having to update each csproj when something needs to change in all of them. What I've looked at so far:

- Usa a csproj generator to generate a somewhat templated csproj and copy over the .cs files in a temporary build folder and build from there, the issue here is the different references as well as this taking time on the whole copy pasting as well as it being brittle.
- Using Roslyn to create a build app that will compile each .cs file, but this starts getting complicated once I need to add references from the CLR and even more so when adding nuget packages, so it seems I need a more "batteries included" approach, which lead me to the next attempt.
- Overriding the built in `Build` step in msbuild by using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47619786/3073551) approach, but other then using `cpc` directly I can't find the actual `Build` step in the [SDK](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/blob/main/src/Tasks/Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets) so I can copy the relevant things and override the ones I need. (I might be missing something obvious here as this is quite new to me)

So the question is how to achieve this either through extending msbuild or an approach that I have not considered so far.

Comment: What is that you need to change in all projects?

Comment: @PauloMorgado Most often it's bumping versions on libraries used in all projects, before that it was changing from System.Data.Sql to Microsoft.Data.SQL and before that adding custom postbuild steps to copy over some legal text etc etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways you can centrally manage concerns common to several projects and were designed just for that and supported:

- [Customize your build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build)

  - [Directory.Build.props and Directory.Build.targets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build#directorybuildprops-and-directorybuildtargets)
- [Central Package Management (CPM)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/Central-Package-Management)

The project system was not designed for what you're trying to do, and it's not supported. And you'll waste more time maintaining it than what you have today.